# Can I import the version-4 for "cublas" whereas import version-5 for "cudart" library at the same time?

Tags: cuda, cublas

It may sound weird, but the situation is, after upgrading CUDA4 to CUDA5, I found that my own kernel is running faster, but the cublas functions (eg cublasDgemm) becomes slower. Also, cublasDgemm seems calling some magma stuff in version 5.

So, I wonder whether I could import the version-4 for "cublas" whereas import version-5 for "cudart" library. As a simple trial, I have a code (mycode.cc):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cublas.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int ver;
    cudaRuntimeGetVersion(&ver);
    cout<<"cudart version: "<<ver<<endl;

    cublasHandle_t hdl;
    cublasCreate(&hdl);
    cublasGetVersion(hdl, &ver);
    cout<<"cublas version: "<<ver<<endl;
}
```

and tried:

```
g++ -I /opt/cuda/include/ -L /opt/cuda/lib64/ -lcudart -I /opt/cuda-5.0/include/ -L /opt/cuda-5.0/lib64/ -lcublas mycode.cc
```

My system has a "module" setup, and I tried both for "module load cuda4" and "module load cuda5". Interestingly, it compiled when "module load cuda4", and then it reported:

```
cudart version: 4010
cublas version: 4010
```

which is not what I wanted for cudart. Moreover, when I "module load cuda5", it still compiled, but running the excutable failed with:

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: There is verisoning in the runtime and you cant mix runtimes or libraries built on the runtime. So, no, this wont work.

Comment: Also why include *both* `cublas.h` and `cublas_v2.h`? You should pick one API and use only it...

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for reminding. I kinda remember when I originally referred to cublas4.0 manual, some new features were included in cutlas_v2.h, but we still need to include cutlas.h for some basic features. It's worth a double check anyway.

Comment: @talonmies Despite the impossibility, do you have any comments on why cublas5 is slower and internally different from cublas4 as I pointed out in the post?

Comment: No I don't have any comment beyond this: if you have found what you think is a performance regression in CUBLAS 5, make a repro case and submit a bug report to NVIDIA. Otherwise, I don't see much of s Stack Overflow question in any of this....

Answer (score 1):

There is verisoning in the runtime and you can't mix runtime versions, nor libraries built on different runtime versions. So, no, this won't work because CUBLAS 4.2 requires the CUDA 4.2 runtime library and cannot work with CUDA 5.0.

[This answer added from comments as a community wiki answer to get the question off the unanswered list]